# IIDR CDC Kafka on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, cdc, ibm-infosphere, ibm-data-replication

We are trying to publish data form db2-IIDR (IBM CDC) to Kafka on AWS . Subscription fails due to below error-

```
 An error occurred during the conversation with Kafka. 
    Error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for cdckafka-subsname-commitstream-0
```

Are there any pre-requisites to be performed to publish the streams from IIDR to Kafka on aws ?

Some more details -

-Kafka cluster is running on AWS

-IIDR CDC engines --> on premise (both source and target)

-On premise IPs have been white-listed and I can ping/telnet ports from on-prem to aws and vice versa .

Thanks!

Comment: You're a bit light on detail here :) What's your deployment look like in terms of network? Everything local to AWS? How have you configured Kafka for the network? etc

Comment: @Robin - I have edited the question . Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up your Kafka brokers with listeners that will work with external clients. You can see [details here](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/).

Simply pinging from client on-premises to AWS is not enough - you need to validate it with a Kafka client such as `kafkacat`